# Is there a way to pass result of localstorage:getItem() to activity from webview

Tags: javascript, android, local-storage, android-webview, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Am using webview to load a page in android. Once the page is loaded, localstorage is updated. I want to retrieve data from it. Above kitkat, using evaluateJavascript am able to obtain the data. It have a callback.  The problem is with versions below kitkat, where i have to use loadUrl() for it.

```
loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.getItem('"+ key +"')");
```

I want to pass the value returned by function getItem(), to calling activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it. First you need to add javascript interface to your webview like this. Lets say you are loading url in some activity called FormDetailActivity:

```
final FormBridge formBridge = new FormBridge(FormDetailActivity.this);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(formBridge, "Android");
```

formBridge is the instance of a class where all the methods are written that are being called from js.

```
public class FormBridge extends Activity {


private static final String TAG = "FormBridge";

Context mContext;


private FormDetailActivity mFormActivity;



/**
 * Instantiate the interface and set the context
 */
public FormBridge(Context c) {
    mContext = c;

    mFormActivity = (FormDetailActivity) mContext;

}



@JavascriptInterface
public String getLocalStorageFromJs(String someStringFromJs) {
    //here you'll get the string from js
}
}
```

And to pass the key from java to your js you need to make a method in js accepting key param and then you can call it like this:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
               view.loadUrl("javascript:getStringFromLocalStorage('"+key+"')");

                }
            });
```

And then call this method from your js like:

```
function getStringFromLocalStorage(key){
   Android.getLocalStorageFromJs(localStorage.getItem(key));
}
```

Comment: I saw this in developers page. I was confused about how will i call the function getLocalStorageFromJs(). Can you tell what you meant by 'call this method from js'?

Comment: that means where your javascript code is written. you can access the javascript code my declaring interface.

Comment: This might sound silly. I know JavaScript Interface is the way to go. My problem is, what is this file, where you put the function, 'getStringFromLocalStorage()'. Even i have made a similar class and made a @JavascriptInterface annoted fucntion. But after calling that using loadUrl(), the function is not called. Its not getting linked. The only thing missing is the last 'function()', you have used.

Comment: Are you loading file first? like 

mWebView.loadUrl("file:///" + file);

after this onPageFinished you need to call js method like view.loadUrl("javascript:getStringFromLocalStorage('"+key+"')"); I did above ini my answer

Comment: No. Am just loading a url in webview. Should i put this function in the webpage that am calling?

Comment: yes first load the file in which your webview code is written like this mWebView.loadUrl("file:///" + file); 
then handle the call back of webview like this mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
               view.loadUrl("javascript:getStringFromLocalStorage('"+key+"')");

                }
            });

Comment: Okay. So this function should exist in the webpage being loaded. Thus, using the "javascript:", am able to access it. And i believe, 'Android', might be an existing class.
Am i right?

Comment: yes, function needs to be there in webpage and after loading the page you need to call that method